# Creating onDoneBlock with multiple strings

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, nsdictionary

In my application I store workouts as a NSDictionary(exercise, sets, reps, kg and notes), but I want to store each individual as a string. I have an own class for creating workouts(ExerciseCreator.swift). The onDoneBlock is like this: `var onDoneBlock : ((NSDictionary) -> Void)?`

Now the code is used like this:

```
//Creating a dictionary from the exercise values
var exerciseDictionary: NSDictionary!

exerciseDictionary =  ["Exercise" : exerciseNameTextField.text!, "Sets" : String(format: "%d", setCount), "Reps" : String(format: "%d", repsCount), "KG" : String(format: "%d", kgCount)]

//Closing modal and refreshing tableview on parent view controller
if let callback = self.onDoneBlock {
       callback (exerciseDictionary)
}
```

In my main view controller, the code is as the following:

```
let exerciseCreator = ExerciseCreator()
        exerciseCreator.viewReady = {() -> Void in}
        exerciseCreator.onDoneBlock = {(dict) -> Void in
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                self.exercisesArray.add(dict)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                print("Exercises: \(self.exercisesArray)")
            })
        }
```

How can I accomplish the same, but using strings instead of NSDictionary?

Comment: Where you define your done block ?

Comment: @CodeChanger The `var onDoneBlock : ((NSDictionary) -> Void)?` and `if let callback = self.onDoneBlock { ` is in a own class named ExerciseCreator.swift. The usage(last code) is in my main view controller(HomeViewController.swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your block declaration like below

```
var onDoneBlock : ((Array<Any>) -> Void)?
```

Also update param name like below

```
self.onDoneBlock = {(arrayVal) -> Void in
      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
          self.exercisesArray.add(arrayVal)
          self.tableView.reloadData()
          print("Exercises: \(self.exercisesArray)")
      })
}
```

and pass your array like this

```
//Closing modal and refreshing tableview on parent view controller
if let callback = self.onDoneBlock {
      callback (arrayObject)
}
```

edit:

for string array pass values like this

```
if let callback = self.onDoneBlock {
     callback (["Test1","Test2","Test3"])
}
```

Hope this will helps!

Comment: Thanks for you contribution, I had a mistake in my question. I ment that I want to pass multiple strings, not an array. Updated question now.

Comment: as per my answer you can pass array of string in that block as I made it with <Any> object so you can pass string array in it.